# Android google maps return error and blue screen

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem with google maps. I generate key and paste in good place but when I see map only what i got is blue screen like on the picture: [image]

and error:

```
06-22 09:18:08.363: W/MapActivity(19369): Recycling dispatcher android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher@2b11ce08
06-22 09:18:08.373: V/MapActivity(19369): Recycling map object.
06-22 09:18:08.573: I/MapActivity(19369): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
06-22 09:18:08.573: E/MapActivity(19369): Couldn't get connection factory client
```

Could you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457729/android-maps-cannot-show

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199403/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is ok. Works great. This blue screen is sea :) I am so stupid :)

Comment: So centre of equator and Greenwich Meridian, puts you in the Atlantic :)

Comment: @user1302569 how can i determine it is pointing to ocean and how to prevent such situation